# how to solve error {"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}

Tags: php, json, twitter

I want to fetch all public posts from twitter. Create an app in twitter and gather Consumer Key `(API Key)`,Consumer Secret `(API Secret)`,Access Level,Access Token,Access Token Secret,Access Level and write a program. At the run time it shows an error

`{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}`.

create a class for twitterapi where all keys are private then set post. Then create a function setGetfield()

```
public function setGetfield($string)
    {
        if (!is_null($this->getPostfields())) 
        { 
            throw new Exception('You can only choose get OR post fields.'); 
        }

        $search = array('#', ',', '+', ':');
        $replace = array('%23', '%2C', '%2B', '%3A');
        $string = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);  

        $this->getfield = $string;

        return $this;
    }
```

Create a function getGetfields() for collect all field from twitter.

```
public function getGetfields()
    {
        return $this->getfield;
    }
```

to build oauth write buildOuath fuction

```
 public function buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    {
        if (!in_array(strtolower($requestMethod), array('post', 'get')))
        {
            throw new Exception('Request method must be either POST or GET');
        }

        $consumer_key = $this->consumer_key;
        $consumer_secret = $this->consumer_secret;
        $oauth_access_token = $this->oauth_access_token;
        $oauth_access_token_secret = $this->oauth_access_token_secret;

        $oauth = array( 
            'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
            'oauth_nonce' => time(),
            'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
            'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token,
            'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
            'oauth_version' => '1.0'
        );

        $getfield = $this->getGetfield();

        if (!is_null($getfield))
        {
            $getfields = str_replace('?', '', explode('&', $getfield));
            foreach ($getfields as $g)
            {
                $split = explode('=', $g);
                $oauth[$split[0]] = $split[1];
            }
        }

        $base_info = $this->buildBaseString($url, $requestMethod, $oauth);
        $composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
        $oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
        $oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;

        $this->url = $url;
        $this->oauth = $oauth;

        return $this;
    }
```

To generate authorisation header

```
 private function buildAuthorizationHeaders($oauth) 
    {
        $return = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
        $values = array();

        foreach($oauth as $key => $value)
        {
            $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
        }

        $return .= implode(', ', $values);
        return $return;
    }
```

how to solve this difficulty

Comment: What did  you try to do that?

Comment: I am trying to build an application using PHP, where i want to fetch the public posts of twitter without login in the twitter. To do that I need some API keys for authentication. I got that all, but while run my code I got this error

Comment: I'm asking for the code that you have written.

Comment: @ Manish Jangir Blogaddition, I am also facing same problem. Please tell me.